# Is there a way to compare scanned folders with those in database?

Tags: php

Miken32 i gat what u said, but what is happening us that i have many folders in the directory, so i want to display those folders that are similar to those in the database

Comment: I don't see compare in your code. You take a folder name from DB and build folders list, but not compare one to another.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow @Giftbanda. sorry, what is the question?